# ubuntu assign 2 local ip's to on machine

Tags: networking

Explanation:
I have one Ethernet port that on my server and i want my services to be routed through a VPN. e.g. nordVPN / Mullvad.
I would also like to a reverse proxy running on the server that is port forwarded. Meaning I CAN'T have the reverse proxy effected by the VPN.
What's the best way to tacle this?
fyi. its on a raspberry pi, so it cant run 2 VM's

Comment: First contact NordVPN find out if you can even do that using their software. Second what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: using 22.04 ubuntu server. im not too worried on the vpn providers software as many support using the default opnevpn/wireguard programs